# Deploying azure web site locally, update-database doesn't work: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure, web

I have done this tutorial:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/?redirectToLocale=false

It works when I publish it on my Azure online account, and the database is running well.
But the problem is that when I followed the tutorial, it asks to do this:
1. enable-migrations
2. add-migrations
3. update-database

1. and 2. works but when I run 3. (update-database) in the Package Manager Console, I get this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

So I can't deploy my WebSite locally and this is my problem...
When I run Ctrl+F5, it opens

```
> http://localhost:2700/
```

and it shows this error:

```
> Server Error in '/' Application.
> 
> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
> 
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Check the stack trace for more information
> about the error and where it originated in the code.
> 
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE
> Permission denied in database 'master'.
> 
> Source Error:
> 
> 
> Line 20: public ActionResult Index ()
> Line 21: { 
> Line 22:   return View(db.ToDoItems.ToList ()); 
> Line 23: } 
> 
> Source File: c: \ Users \ baudouin \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2012 \
> Projects \ ToDoListApp \ ToDoListApp \ Controllers \ HomeController.cs
> Line: 22
```

When I open SQL Server Management Studio, I do have access to my master database...
When I am in Visual Studio 2012 RC, it says that my data connection DefaultConnection(ToDoApp) has an error:

```
> Server Explorer can not execute this operation.
>     For more information, see details below:
>     Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\baudouin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ToDoListApp\ToDoListApp\App_Data\aspnet-ToDoListApp-20120625114938.mdf'
> as database 'aspnet-ToDoListApp-20120625114938'.
```

I do not see in the tutorial what corresponds to that .mdf ... and I don't understand why update-database is not working at all.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you !!
[A french student from Paris]

Answer (score 0):

What is your connection string? It seems you are trying to connect to local SQLExpress DB while testing your code?

When you are running  code from Visual Studio, both VS and database could be running on two different accounts. For example Windows Azure Compute Emulator runs with "Network Service" account credentials so add same "Network Service" credentials for master database solves the problem.

So try adding login to your SQLExpress instance for NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and grant it sysadmin role and see if the problem is resolved.

Despite granting sys admin role grant db_owner role to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE only for the Master DB.This also requires restarting the services once-advisable to restart the system.

Comment: My connection string is:
`Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\baudouin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ToDoListApp\ToDoListApp\App_Data\aspnet-ToDoListApp-20120625114938.mdf";Initial Catalog=aspnet-ToDoListApp-20120625114938;Integrated Security=True`
But I don't know what is the .mdf..I guess I should be telling him to go locally, but how do I do that ?
In the tutorial it says:`(Unless you have SQL Server Express installed, in which case the database is created using the SQL Server Express instance.)`
Yes I am trying to connect to local SQLExpress DB. Thx !

Comment: Do you have MDF in above location or does it still exist? MDF is your SQL Express local database and this is where your SQL code is being executed.

Comment: Hi, no I don't have mdf here ..\aspnet-ToDoListApp-20120625114938‌​.mdf
I'm not sure how to tell it to go locally. Is that in the Publish settings (when right-clicking the project name) ? or is it in the Data Connections ?
Thx

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Avkash, the issue is related to you’re trying to connect to a local database. This may work locally, but it won’t work in Windows Azure. Please use Azure SQL database. The connection string’s data source need to point to tcp:… instead of a local mdf file. Actually the tutorial you pointed out already uses Azure SQL database, please refer to it for more detailed information.

Comment: Why is this nonsense being peddled by an MSFT employee? The tutorial clearly states that it creates a local database. Following the steps given in the tutorial will result in this error, as I have just discovered myself. Please try reading and understanding the tutorial before you answer.